# Is it possible to use React in Django project "partially"?

Tags: reactjs, django

This may be a weird question, and not exactly about programming itself, but let me elaborate anyway. I hope you understand. 
So I myself am not a professional programmer, only learned Django this year to build the prototype of a web service I'm thinking. Now I'm able to create a basic CRUD application using Django for both front and back end. 
Then I recently started co-working with a full-stack programmer, who uses React for front-end and Django for back-end. In our project, there are several independent applications, with separate templates/views/models of course, and I decided to take one of them and work on it since we were running out of time.
The problem is that I know nothing about React, so I thought I would work on the application purely with Django, and he could work on the rest of the project with React+Django. 
In this case, is it possible to "work on some parts of the project purely with Django and the rest with React+Django combination"? Or would it cause any problem or error in the entire project?
Thank you very much in advance. Please let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `backend`, it can be possible and many do that, but with different servers that have special services for defined tasks.

but for the `front`, personally, never seen an approach like this, but It's not likely that it be possible.
there are different dependencies in the project for both `Django` and `react`. maybe with two different servers, it is possible, but it's not recommended.

if you try to learn the concepts of `react` and do your part in react it will be a cleaner code.

Comment: Thanks. The application that I'm trying to work on is independent from others except for Users and stuff. So I figured it'd be possible. By the way I've gone through some React and React+Django tutorials but I'm short in time at the moment so I was looking for faster and simpler ways. Thank you for the reply anyway. :)

Comment: oh ,ok I just shared my information, I hope you find a faster way and if you did would be nice if you share here.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to partially use React in your Django application, but instead of using `create-react-app` you can use `<script>` tags to use react.

Add these two `<script>` tags to the HTML page:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

Also, don't forget to minify your javascript files to make your website production-ready.

Follow this to learn more: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html